# Flame: Forming a component from a repeated image

Tags: flutter, flame

I'm making a simple game in flutter / flame.  I have a brick-wall image, something like this:
https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/oga-textures/97263/brick_wall.png

If I want to make a large brick wall, then I can tile this image onscreen, and it looks like a single brick wall.  One way to do that in flame would be to create `SpriteComponent` for each image, and place them on the screen side-by-side.  That's a bit messy, creating a lot of components each with their own hitbox.  Is there a way to create a single component, and tell flame to repeat the image many times in order to fill the available space?

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Wall component that will hold RectangleHitbox as a whole, while each Brick can be responsible to hold Sprite image. You will need to iterate over width and height, and will have more control about things like size, scale etc.